# How to make useEffect rerender after the data is changed?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, use-effect, use-state

I want the useEffect to fetch and render `rooms` data. And rerender the data when the new room is being added to `rooms`

Code to fetch data and display data with useEffect and an empty dependency.

```
const [rooms, setRooms] = useState([]);

  const getRoomsData = async () => {
    const querySnapshot = await getDocs(collection(db, "rooms"));
    const data = querySnapshot.docs.map((doc) => ({
      id: doc.id,
      data: doc.data(),
    }));

    setRooms(data);
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    getRoomsData();
    console.log("rerendered");
  }, []);
```

With this code, after I added new room to `rooms`. I need to manually refresh the page to see the new data rendered. What should I do to make it rerender itself after new "room" is added to `rooms`?

Code to add room:

```
    const roomName = prompt("please enter name for chat room");

    if (roomName) {
      addDoc(collection(db, "rooms"), {
        name: roomName,
      });
    }
  };
```

I tried adding rooms to the useEffect dependency, which has the result I want (no need to refresh), but it is only because it is rendering infinitely, which is bad. What is the proper way of doing it?

Comment: How do you *know* when `data` has changed in order to enqueue a state update? Are you using firebase? Isn't there an `onSnapshot` method to be used on a collection?

Comment: Yes I am using firebase. So basically I want my app to rerender after I adding docs into my firebase collection "rooms". I want my app to fetch the data and rerender it, so I don't have to refresh the page to see the updated data. How do I do that?

Comment: I see, so you know when the data has changed because you just added it. What happens if you invoke `getRoomsData` at the end of the "add room" code to refetch the data?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can think of two approaches to solving this problem, without having to use `useEffect`, the first one being a workaround where you update the `rooms` state locally without having to fetch it from the server, i.e, you are basically constructing and appending an object to the existing array of `rooms`, this is possible only if you know the structure of the object, looking at your `getRoomsData` function, it seems that you are returning a data array with each item having the following object structure.

```
{
 id: <DOCUMENT_ID>,
 data: {
  name: <ROOM_NAME>
 }
}
```

So, when you add a room, you can do something like this:

```
   const roomName = prompt("please enter name for chat room");

    if (roomName) {
      addDoc(collection(db, "rooms"), {
        name: roomName,
      });
      let newRoom = {
        id: Math.random(), //random id
        data: {
          name: roomName
        }
      }
      setRooms([...rooms,newRoom])
  };
```

This way, you can also reduce the number of network calls, which is a performance bonus, but the only downside is that you've to be sure about the object structure so that the results are painted accordingly.

In case, you are not sure of the object structure, what you could do is instead invoke `getRoomsData` after you add your new room to the collection, like so:

```
   const roomName = prompt("please enter name for chat room");

    if (roomName) {
      addDoc(collection(db, "rooms"), {
        name: roomName,
      }).then(res=>{
          getRoomsData();
      })
  };
```

This is would ensure to fetch the latest data (incl. the recently added room) and render your component with all the results.
In either of the methods you follow, you could use your `useEffect` only once when the component mounts with an empty dependency array.

```
 useEffect(() => {
    getRoomsData();
    //console.log("rerendered");
  }, []);
```

By doing this, you first basically display the data when the user visits this page for the first time/when the components mount for the first time. On subsequent additions, you can either append the newly added `room` as an object to the `rooms` array after adding it to the database or add it to the database and fetch all the results again, so that the latest addition is rendered on the screen.

Answer (score 1):

You are getting infinite re-renders because the function inside the `useEffect` is updating the state of `rooms` which is in the dependency array of the effect.  This will always cause infinite re-renders.

To answer your question verbatim:
"How do I make it rerender only when the data is changed?"

Since `rooms` and `data` are set to be the same, you can keep your `useEffect` how it is, but then create another `useEffect` to fire only when the component mounts to call `getRoomsData()`.

```
const [rooms, setRooms] = useState([]);

  const getRoomsData = async () => {
    const querySnapshot = await getDocs(collection(db, "rooms"));
    const data = querySnapshot.docs.map((doc) => ({
      id: doc.id,
      data: doc.data(),
    }));

    setRooms(data);
  };

  useEffect(() = > {
    getRoomsData();
  }, [])

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log("rerendered");
  }, [rooms]);
```

I think the real crux of solving your issue is knowing when to call `getRoomsData()`, because depending on that, you will change the `useEffect` dependency array to fit that need.

Comment: Thanks for the answer but I am still confused. How do I run ```getRoomsData``` whenever I add some data in the "rooms" doc from my collection? I am displaying rooms data and user can add more room. And in order to display the new room that added on screen I have to refresh the page, which I don't like. How do I rerender and display the data when new "room" is added to "rooms" without refreshing?

Comment: That will depend entirely on the rest of the code.  If you edit your question to include more code, I can give you a definite answer on that.  How are you adding the `rooms` to the db?  I don't know which db you're using.

Comment: Sorry, I may have not explained my issue properly previously, I have edited the question. Thank you. And I am using firebase btw.